# Replacing a data outputted by innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText

Tags: jquery

There is a table/html output I am accessing from a remote server, and in this table/html output there is a word "Blah blah" right above the table. How do I get rid of this or replace it?

I tried the code below but I can't seem to get rid of it or replace it. I'm guessing it's not in a table since I tried table, tr, td, tbody, etc.:

```
$("td").filter(function(){ return $(this).text() == 'Blah blah';}).text('')
```

Comment: Probably I'm wrong, but if it's "above" the table, why are you searching in TD's?

Comment: I'm just using TD as an example. I tried table, tr, tbody also and it's still there. It may not even be in a table. In that case, how would I remove or replace that?

Comment: can't you just use one replace all in the string responseText?

Comment: How would I code that?

Comment: i will post an answer with that

Answer (score 0):

Use the `replace function` of the string before setting the `innerHTML`, here is an example of the code

```
<script>
var responseText = "Blah Blah<table><tr><td>Hi Table</td></tr></table>";
function test(){
    var t = responseText.replace("Blah Blah", "");
    document.getElementById('d').innerHTML = t;

}

</script>
 <button onclick="test()">test</button>
  <div id="d"></div>
```

Comment: That removes the entire HTML and table, but at least it removed "Blah blah". Where else can we place "t" so the rest of the HTML displays? I'm already using `document.getElementById("datatable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;`.

Comment: var t = xmlhttp.responseText.replace("Blah Blah", ""); document.getElementById("datatable").innerHTML=t; it shouldnt remove the entire html, it only remove that string... if you checked my example, you can see that the table is rendered

Comment: It still doesn't work. Any other way like my original post or `$("td:contains('Blah')").html("");`? Thing is, I don't know if "Blah" is in a table since tbody, tr, td does not delete it.

Comment: do you want to remove the "Blah" or the table structure that hold it?

Comment: The table structure that holds it.

Comment: ok, you didnt make that clear on your question... I dont know how to do that with jquery, what you can do with the replace function is to add the the table tags to it.. like: .replace("<td>Blah Blah</td>", "")

Comment: How do I code this so I don't have to click a button? I just want "Blah blah" removed. Thanks.

Comment: @user2430338 just invoke this code in the callback of the ajax function... where you get the response of the server

Comment: This works now. What I did was simply add `.replace("Blah blah", "");` to `document.getElementById("datatable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText` like this `document.getElementById("datatable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText.replace("Virtual Queue", "");`. Thank you fmodos.